# Message appears every time terminal is opened

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

On OS X Mavericks, whenever I open up iTerm (or the default Terminal), the following message appears:

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

This slows down the process of opening a new terminal instance, so it is very annoying. The normal command line will work after those messages pop up. I noticed this started happening after I upgraded from OS X 10.8 to 10.9. I'm not sure why this is happening, is there any way I can address this problem?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** The problem is because RVM was installed on 10.8, but was removed in the upgrade to 10.9. However, it didn't remove what it modified in `/etc/profile`. I just removed the two lines that it added, and then it removed the notice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hunt around and fix the problem, put a bandage over it:

```
for script in /etc/profile.d/{sm,rvm}.sh; do
    sudo ln -s /bin/true $script
done
```

If you want to fix it properly, look at all the [bash startup files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) (and *everything* they source) to see who's calling those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To fix any issues with sourcing RVM use:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

It will remove existing sourcing lines and add new ones that are meant to work.

Or a quick and dirty hack would be to execute:

```
touch /etc/profile.d/{sm,rvm}.sh
```